# Geometry Nodes: How do I Combine Cylinder Top & Bottom into Selection Input?

Tags: geometry-nodes

What node do I need to use to combine the Top & Bottom outputs of the Cylinder node into the selection input of the Delete Geometry node?

[image]

Comment: The node [Boolean Math](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/utilities/math/boolean_math.html) will be helpful in this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are Boolean values (is)Top, and (is)Bottom, so the *Boolean Math*: (is) Top **OR** Bottom, does the job:

[image]

..incidentally, equivalent to a clamped *Math > Add*.

Of course, in this particular case, you could have created the cylinder with 'Fill Type > None' in the first place.

Comment: Thanks Robin!  And LOL about the Fill Type, you're right I could do that. I'm actually working on something a little more complex but this seemed like the simplest way to illustrate my question. Cheers ;)